# ImportError: No module named 'cv2' on Watson Studio

Tags: watson-studio

The command

```
import cv2
```

on Watson Studio results in the error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-1-72fbbcfe2587> in <module>()----> 1 import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I'm not sure if I need to install opencv upfront and how to do this in a cloud environment like Watson Studio?

Comment: Maybe use `pip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cv2 is part of opencv-python package.
Please  install the pypi hosted libararies using `!pip` magic in jupyter notebook.

```
!pip install opencv-python
```

Then run the import cv2.

See this shared notebook

https://dataplatform.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/a0e50c53-ea28-4b78-800f-35cae2211389/view?access_token=b129fa46626e1bf317de18c9241af375d9a9ac8e11561e3735569050fe0b8839

Also see this documentation for installing third party libraries.

https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/importing-libraries.html